# How can i stay on the same page?

Tags: jquery

i have checkboxes on my page and remove values from db with ajax. The problem is that when i click for removing, it sends to me the index page , what i want is that staying where i remove the checkbox.

This is my code. What might be the changes , if i want to stay on the same page.

```
function deleteData() {
    var artistIds = [];
    $("input[name='artist[]']:checked").each(function () {
        artistIds.push($(this).val());
    });
    alert(artistIds);
    var sitepath = 'http://www.sinemalar.com/';
    $.post('/management/deleteDataAjax2', {
        json: JSON.stringify({
            'artistIds': artistIds
        })
    }, function (response) {
        alert("Başarıyla silindi");
        window.location.replace(window.location.pathname);
    });
}
```

Comment: Check: [PreventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

Comment: What does your `form` (I guess you have one) markup look like?

Comment: How is the `deleteData()` method called ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stay on the same page, you should remove

```
window.location.replace(window.location.pathname);
```

Comment: yeah it works but actually i need to refresh to show the changes . is there a way ?

Comment: If you need to show the changes, why not use the ajax to update the page?

Answer (score 0):

If you change window.location then you're going to load a new webpage.

It isn't possible to change the location appearing in the navigation bar because of the potential this has for malicious use.

If you're wanting to somehow represent the change in page in the navigation bar, look into using the window.location.hash as well as [history.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/).